# Best practice for handling POST request in PHP

Tags: php, post

I'm working on a PHP project which has many pages calling a POST request, such as login, register, commenting and etc.

I've tried processing all POST requests in a single file named post.php, with each request containing 'formtype' parameter, like so,

```
$formtype = $_POST['formtype'];
if ($formtype == "register") {
    register_function_here();
} else if ($formtype == 'login') {
    login_function_here();
} else {
    die("Error: No FORMTYPE");
}
```

and I've also tried having separate files for separate functions, such as login.php, register.php, comment.php and etc.

Which method is better for processing POST requests?
Are there any disadvantages for processing all POST requests in a single file, as I've done?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: MVC with separate controller methods for the POST is how I like to do it, but that's not something that can be done easily without using a framework

Comment: MVC pattern, or even better, CQRS pattern should fit your needs, at least if you want go ahead with your knowledge. You can find plenty of documentation regarding these patterns on internet.

Comment: The more code you try and squeeze into one script, the more of a headache it probably will become, seperation of concerns helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you mean you do not want to:

```
GET index.php
POST user/register.php
POST user/login.php

index.php
user/
    register.php
    login.php
404.php
```

What @ArtisticPhoenix about the MVC (model, view, controller) is actually what you tried. Well, for the Controller part i mean.
You try to create **router**.

You could do that. If you are new to coding and you got time i even would say: do it.
If you dont have time and need a solution then i suggest searching a framework - at least for routing.

---

To get started:

First i found was this: https://www.taniarascia.com/the-simplest-php-router/

If you want to go further then you SHOULD start using OOP.
A class is then a controller, a method an action.
(some got like every action is a class like zend expressive framework).

Example:

Create a routing config

```
// file: config/routes.php
return [
    'routes' => [
        [
            'path'            => "/login",
            'class'           => LoginController::class,
            'method'          => 'loginAction',
            'allowed_methods' => ['POST'],
        ],
        [
            'path'            => "/logout",
            'class'           => LoginController::class,
            'method'          => 'logoutAction',
            'allowed_methods' => ['GET', 'POST'],
        ],
        // ...
    ],
];
```

Create Controllers

```
// file: Controller/LoginController.php
namespace Controller;
class LoginController
{
    public function loginAction()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public function logoutAction()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now use the requested path and `route` it to the controller.

If no route found then return a HTTP 404 "Not Found" response .

```
// file: index.php
// load routing config
$routes = require 'config/routes.php';
// ...
// ... this now is up to you. 
// you should search in the config if the requested path exists
// and if the request is in the allowed_methods
// and then create a new controller and call the method.
```

Comment: Having a config/routes folder seems like a pain to me, any time you want to rename, add or remove a method or add a controller you'd need to remember to also update the router.  I prefer to have a routefinder class that checks the controller exists, and then let the controller decide if the method(request) is valid and sets a fallback if not.  This way any changes or new classes are  independent of the routefinder, and vice versa.  You can also fal back to a generic error at a top level of the request and default are both invalid

Comment: @jameson2012 you mean like a dynamic router? `/foo/bar` to `FooController::barAction` (if exists)? Sure, some do this. But this _could_ cause "problems". F.e. a controller that actually should have been disabled. Or some day the "/controller/method"-pattern does not fit your needs anymore. Or you just need to disable a controller "real quick". Config-driven routing has imo more advantage|control. But ofc depends ...

Comment: Yeah it's horses for courses really and the preference of the architect - in both your examples though I can always just return a false in a controllers construct so I always only have 1 place to look - it's more a comment on my lack of memory/inclination  most likely!   Either way it's nice to have options! :)

Answer (score -1):

I strongly recommend Object Oriented Programming, using classes, one source file per class.